# Linear Transformation one to one and onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Let $A = 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc} 
5 & -4 & 5 \\
1 & -2 & -1 \\
-1 & 5 & 6 \end{array}  
\right].$

Is the linear transformation $T : \mathbb{R}^3 → \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $T(x) = Ax$
one-to-one? onto? Is the vector $v = \left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
−1\\
0 
\end{array}
\right]$ 
in the range of T?

The answer from my professor is that it's not onto, nor one to one and the vector is not in the range.

I don't understand though. There is a pivot in every row for matrix A, so it should span R3 right? It should also be one to one because there are no free variables.

I also tested the vector and it has a unique solution. Can someone explain to me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

To determine whether a linear transformation is one-to-one or onto, you do not just look at the matrix itself, you look at the reduced row echelon form. Notably, if you put this matrix in RREF, you get: $$\text{rref}(A) = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & \frac{7}{3} \\
0 & 1 & \frac{5}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right].$$

So this matrix does is not of full rank and thus cannot span, i.e. it is not onto. A linear transformation from $V \rightarrow V$ is one-to-one iff it is onto iff it is bijective as long as $V$ is finite-dimensional as we have here.

Hope this helps!

Edit: As for showing this particular vector is not in the range, you write $$A\cdot \left[\begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right]$$ and solve which is equivalent to putting the augmented matrix $$\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
5 & -4 & 5 & 1 \\
1 & -2 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & 5 & 6 & 0 
\end{array}\right]$$ and placing it in reduced row echelon form again.

When we do so, we get:

$$\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & \frac{7}{3} & 0 \\
0 & 1 & \frac{5}{3} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{array}\right]$$ where the last row implies $0x_1 + 0x_2 + 0x_3 = 1$, a contradiction. Thus this system has no solution.